# Can we switch between multiple FCM projects at runtime?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-play-services

We're using Firebase Cloud Messaging feature in our Android application which is meant to be used by multiple clients.
In our Android application we integrated the "google-services.json" file as suggested [here](https://wizyapp.appspot.com/k/u/e/a59519b59300b923682bef860863734e?a=aHR0cHM6Ly9maXJlYmFzZS5nb29nbGUuY29tL2RvY3MvYW5kcm9pZC9zZXR1cA%3D%3D).

The problem is that each of our clients uses a separate Firebase project, whereas, in that file, we can set only ONE Firebase project credentials :

```
"project_info": {
    .....
  },
```

So the question is : 
Is it possible, in Android app, to **switch between different firebase projects** (or different "google-services.json" files) **at** **RUNTIME**?

**PS :** I can't see how could this topic be a duplicate of any of the existing topics, since I specifically mentioned that I'd like to switch between Firebase projects "**at RUNTIME**", not "at build". So the suggested duplicate topic, is NOT really a duplicate. Thank you.

Comment: I asked a similar question, which you might like to follow
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57767950/can-my-flutter-app-be-configured-at-runtime-to-use-a-user-custom-fcm-project-set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57767950/can-my-flutter-app-be-configured-at-runtime-to-use-a-user-custom-fcm-project-set)