# Can my flutter app be configured at runtime to use a user custom FCM project settings?

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have developed a flutter app currently running on android, which uses Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) with an embedded google_services.json.

However, I would like users to be able to create their own firebase project and for my app to be able to switch to use their project settings at runtime, rather than use my embedded project settings?

Can I achieve this in flutter using the existing firebase_messaging (5.1.4) plug in? Or will this need to be customised in android/ios code?

I am assuming there will be need to be some sort of oAuth authentication with google before they can re-point to use their FCM project settings. Any guidance, examples would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In other platforms you can explicitly configure a `FirebaseApp` instance, and pass your configuration parameters at run time. It looks like this *is* also possible in Flutter, but I've never tried it myself. See https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_core/latest/firebase_core/FirebaseOptions-class.html

Comment: I encountred same situation with no luck, my current directions are : disable auto inititializations and get rid of the json config file and the plugin, however the flutter plugins are complaining , still looking for a solution, what could be nice is to have the method getToken(senderId, scope) implemented so you can generate device token for secondary app and keep default one side bu side, and then be able to receive both apps nofications and filter them by senderId ....